# Why inserting an Integer into SQLite would bomb out?

Tags: database, xcode, sqlite, fmdb

I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the below insert statement using FMDB executeUpdate.  It occurs on the bindObject toColumn in FMDatabase.

In the NSlog statement, I get the correct values, but the update statement bombs out. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
- (void) addSubject {

    DrillDownAppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (DrillDownAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:appDelegate.getDBPath];    
    [database open];

    NSLog(@"SUBJECT_ID/TITLE/CATEGORY_TITLE = %d / %@ / %@", self.subject_id, self.title, self.category_title);

    [database executeUpdate:@"insert into SUBJECT (subject_id, subject, category) values(?, ?, ?)", 
    self.subject_id, self.title, self.category_title, nil];

    [database close];

}
```

I went through the FMDatabase code and it looks like the first variable, subject_id is the one that is bombing out.  I tried both saving as an NSInteger as well as NSNumber and both gave same crash.

The exact line from FMDatabase where it crashes is:

```
    else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
```

and it is passing the subject_id as an NSInteger (or a NSNumber) and giving the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FMDB executeUpdate statement requires that you use NSNumber and not NSInteger so convert your NSInteger into an NSNumber as part of the executeUpdate statement and it will work.  I spent hours searching for this and finally found it.

Here is an example of how it should look:

```
[database executeUpdate:@"update Subject Set subject = ?, category = ? where subject_id = ?", self.title, self.category_title, [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.subject_id]];
```

Comment: How is NSNumber an "id" value and NSInteger isn't?

Comment: `NSNumber` is an Objective-C class that represents any kind of number. It inherits from `NSValue`, which inherits from `NSObject`. `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger`, on the other hand, are primitive types. These are not Objective-C objects, so they are not convertible to `id`. Objective-C methods that accept a variable number of arguments cannot check for the type of the arguments they receive; this is why it worked at compile-time but crashed at run-time.

Comment: As a general rule, variables of non-pointer types (notice that you need `NSNumber*` but you can go with `NSInteger` without the asterisk) are _rarely_ Objective-C objects. The "exception" are Core Foundation objects, like `CFStringRef` and the like, but that's just because the pointer part is hidden in the `typedef` declaration.